# Отключить увеличение страницы на мобильных устройствах

Tags: веб-программирование, mobile

На мобильных устройствах, если два раза тапнуть по странице - она увеличится. Как это отключить с помощью HTML,CSS,JS?

Comment: В `head` попробуй добавить `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">`

Comment: @ZxNuClear спасибо, помогло

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
body { touch-action: manipulation; }
```

Можно применить к отдельному элементу.
Подробнее: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/touch-action#manipulation